# Splitting images from while loop and renaming in php

Tags: php, for-loop, split, while-loop

I am trying to get images from while loop and split them up at the period (.).. and then change the name of the image to ImageName + -resized. But I can not seem to figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

So in short I have this: image.jpg and I want to create this image-resized.jpg: Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $f = $_GET['f'];
    $h = $_GET['h'];
    $gp = $_GET['gp'];
    //Create folder path
    $path = "Fotos/".$f."/".$h."/".$gp."/";
    //Get pictures from database
    $getfolders = mysql_query("SELECT FolderName, Files FROM Files WHERE FolderDate = '$f' AND FolderHour = '$h' AND FolderName = '$gp'") or die(mysql_error());
    //List pictures from database
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getfolders)){
        $img = $row['Files'];
        //Seperate image at period(.)
        $image = explode('.', $img);
        //Get image name ----------------Here is where I need help!!
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($image); $i++)
          {
          $imag = $image[$i];
          }
        ?>
    <div class="picture" id="pic"><img src="<?php echo $path; echo $imag ?>" alt="picture" /><?php echo $img?></div>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest solution would be:

```
$image = explode('.', $img);
$extension = array_pop($image);
$resizedFileName = implode('.', $image) . "-resized.{$extension}";
```

But this solution does assume, that there are only simple extensions:

```
image.jpg => image-resized.jpg // ok
image.tar.gz => image.tar-resized.gz // not so ok
```

But if there are only simple extensions, this solution might be sufficient.

A better solution would be using [`SplFileInfo`](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/class.splfileinfo.php):

```
$fi = new SplFileInfo($image);
$resizedFileName = $fi->getBasename("." . $fi->getExtension()) . "-resized." . $fi->getExtension();
```

`SplFileInfo::getExtensions()` is available since PHP 5.3.6